# Implementing deserialization with RestSharp and Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: json, deserialization, restsharp, dooh, broadsign

I am rather new to c# but I am building something to help me at work. We have a REST API which I am trying to tap into but I am having issues when it comes to deserializing the response.
My code:

```
namespace BSRestCleint
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        string key = "xxxxxxxx";
        string endPoint = "https://api.broadsign.com:10889/rest";
        private void bRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var client = new RestClient(endPoint);
            var request = new RestRequest("/host/v14/by_id", Method.GET);
            request.AddHeader("accept", "application/json");
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + key);
            request.AddParameter("domain_id", "103947039");
            request.AddParameter("ids", "195392183");
            request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp => { resp.ContentType = "application/json"; };
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            var response = client.Execute<Host>(request);
            var host = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Host>(response.Content);
            oResponse.Text = host.Name;

        }
    }
}
```

And this is my class:

```
namespace BSRestCleint
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using System.Globalization;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
    using System.IO;

    public partial class Host
    {
        [JsonProperty("config_profile_bag_id")]
        public long ConfigProfileBagId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("container_id")]
        public long ContainerId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("db_pickup_tm_utc")]
        public string DbPickupTmUtc { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("discovery_status")]
        public long DiscoveryStatus { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("display_unit_id")]
        public long DisplayUnitId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("domain_id")]
        public long DomainId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("geolocation")]
        public string Geolocation { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("nscreens")]
        public long Nscreens { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("public_key_fingerprint")]
        public string PublicKeyFingerprint { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("remote_clear_db_tm_utc")]
        public string RemoteClearDbTmUtc { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("remote_reboot_tm_utc")]
        public string RemoteRebootTmUtc { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("volume")]
        public long Volume { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Finally the returning json:

```
{  
   "not_modified_since":"2018-06-05T22:22:18Z",
   "host":[  
      {  
         "active":true,
         "config_profile_bag_id":0,
         "container_id":0,
         "db_pickup_tm_utc":"2018-01-11T10:12:55",
         "discovery_status":0,
         "display_unit_id":0,
         "domain_id":103947039,
         "geolocation":"(0,0)",
         "id":195392183,
         "license_end_date":null,
         "licensed":true,
         "name":"Broadsign Services - Mathias - 16x64",
         "nscreens":0,
         "primary_mac_address":"00:0c:29:e0:e6:22",
         "public_key_fingerprint":"REDACTED",
         "remote_clear_db_tm_utc":"1970-01-01T00:00:00",
         "remote_reboot_tm_utc":"2017-12-12T10:17:23",
         "secondary_mac_address":"",
         "volume":-1
      }
   ]
}
```

I know that if I only process this part my code works:

```
{  
     "active":true,
     "config_profile_bag_id":0,
     "container_id":0,
     "db_pickup_tm_utc":"2018-01-11T10:12:55",
     "discovery_status":0,
     "display_unit_id":0,
     "domain_id":103947039,
     "geolocation":"(0,0)",
     "id":195392183,
     "license_end_date":null,
     "licensed":true,
     "name":"Broadsign Services - Mathias - 16x64",
     "nscreens":0,
     "primary_mac_address":"00:0c:29:e0:e6:22",
     "public_key_fingerprint":"REDACTED",
     "remote_clear_db_tm_utc":"1970-01-01T00:00:00",
     "remote_reboot_tm_utc":"2017-12-12T10:17:23",
     "secondary_mac_address":"",
     "volume":-1
}
```

I'd like to know how I could make my code work to handle the whole json so that I don't need to regex the returning value. Some of the responses would return multiple instances unlike there where there's only 1. It's probably a very simple solution but my grasp of the language is rather minute as I am new to it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since, you are getting the host as array inside the another root object so you can define a new class as which is wrapping `Host` (array)

```
public class RootObject
{
    public DateTime not_modified_since { get; set; }
    public List<Host> Host { get; set; }
}
```

deserialization code need to be updated as

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response.Content);
```

If you see, here deserializtion will happen for `RootObject` instead of `Host`.

Now, to get all hosts, use the below code:

```
var hosts = root.Host;
```

Or the first host from received hosts

```
var firstHost = root.Host.First();
```

Comment: When I try to get all the hosts above using this:
 var response = client.Execute<RootObject>(request);
            var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response.Content);
            var hosts = root.Host;
            listBox1.DataSource = root.Host;
Having added your public class RootObject, I get BSRestCleint.Host returned to me.

Comment: `            var response = client.Execute<RootObject>(request);
            var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response.Content);
            var hosts = root.Host;
            listBox1.DataSource = root.Host;
`
Doesn't return any hosts, just this line: **BSRestCleint.Host**

Comment: Check this live fiddle - https://dotnetfiddle.net/5AOq6t . I can see that json is deserialized property. Can you check about assigning to DataSouce is creating this problem?

Comment: It works now! Thank you! I'm able to pull an element out of the host.

Comment: Last question, if you'd like to help further. If I wanted to say produce a table with the key on one side and the value on another side, how would I go about doing that while being able to handle multiple hosts?

Comment: You can check if you can convert to Dictionary<TKey, TValue> to have key on one side and value of another side.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion of how I'll go about doing this with my specific situation considering it's currently a list that can have multiple hosts?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract it like this, without introducing new class:

```
var js = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
var hosts = JArray.Parse(obj["host"].ToString());
foreach (JObject host in hosts)
{
    var h = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Host>(host)
    //do what you need to do with host
}
```

You mentioned that there can be multiple hosts, so, you have to convert it to JArray, and loop through the array.

Answer (score 0):

use this as your Host class instead (renamed to RootObject)

```
    public partial class RootObject
    {
        [JsonProperty("not_modified_since")]
        public DateTimeOffset NotModifiedSince { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("host")]
        public List<Host> Host { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Host
    {
        [JsonProperty("active")]
        public bool Active { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("config_profile_bag_id")]
        public long ConfigProfileBagId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("container_id")]
        public long ContainerId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("db_pickup_tm_utc")]
        public DateTimeOffset DbPickupTmUtc { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("discovery_status")]
        public long DiscoveryStatus { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("display_unit_id")]
        public long DisplayUnitId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("domain_id")]
        public long DomainId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("geolocation")]
        public string Geolocation { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("license_end_date")]
        public object LicenseEndDate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("licensed")]
        public bool Licensed { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("nscreens")]
        public long Nscreens { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("primary_mac_address")]
        public string PrimaryMacAddress { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("public_key_fingerprint")]
        public string PublicKeyFingerprint { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("remote_clear_db_tm_utc")]
        public DateTimeOffset RemoteClearDbTmUtc { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("remote_reboot_tm_utc")]
        public DateTimeOffset RemoteRebootTmUtc { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("secondary_mac_address")]
        public string SecondaryMacAddress { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("volume")]
        public long Volume { get; set; }
    }
}
```

then deserialize

```
var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response.Content);
var hosts = rootObject .Host;
```